# Is it valid to average across forecast errors for series of parts?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, data-transformation, measurement-error, in-sample

I'm trying to do inventory control and measure bias in my forecasts.  I can calculate the forecast error (Demand-Forecast) for each series of parts per month in a 12 month period, but I want to know if I can average across the errors in each month and the cumulative error for 100 part series?

My concern is that some parts have large demands while some have few demands.  12 months are used for in-sample forecasting and 12 months are used for out-of-sample testing.  Do I need to scale each error series first?  Even cumulative errors?

Comment: you can use Weighted Mape to deal with differing levels.

Comment: Would that count as a bias measure?  I was using CFE and Periods in Stock.  For the latter, Kourentzes scales his parts series by the average in-sample period.  I wasn't sure if I could also do that with CFE, especially since some in-sample elements have 1 or a few orders.

Comment: on rereading your question I am not sure that WMAPE is the answer.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. You might be looking for [MASE](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/foresight.pdf)

Comment: Actually, I will be using wMAPE to test the accuracy of my forecasts and CFE and scaled PIS on a selection of parts to test for bias in the forecasts.